# How do I select the child of this iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<div id="google" class="ui-tabs-panel" style="display: block;">
 <iframe id="fre" name="fre" src="http://www.google.com/search?q=xxxx">
  <html>
   .....
  </html>
 </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to make the iframe height equal to the html height
like this

```
document.getElementById("fre").style.height.value = 
document.getElementById("???").style.height();
```

How do I select the html ?

Even if I manage to select it, is it possible to do that with an iframe?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember. To be completely honest, funny thing is that reading this 3 years later, I don't even understand the question.

Comment: @canon Actually I remember, it might be the answer below, although I don't remember testing it. I found some code I probably used, could have been something like this
var $theIframe = document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow;
                var $some_variable = $($theIframe.$.find('.class_a > .active[data-id]')).attr('data-id'); And that's how you select stuff inside the iframe (sorry don't have time to test and write/format an asnwer)

Answer (score 4):

As I recall, you can't access the DOM of an iframe's source unless it's from the same domain.

So, provided the parent/iframe are on the same domain you'll want the iframe's `contentWindow`<sup>1</sup> property... from which you can retrieve the document.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("fre");
var frameDoc = frame.contentWindow.document;
frame.style.height = frameDoc.getElementById("childElementId").style.height;
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> See `HTMLIframeElement.contentWindow`. Depending upon your browser, you may have a `contentDocument` property in lieu of `contentWindow`.</sub>